# How can i close a certain process the user inputted?

Tags: cmd

I am programming a simple program that will close a process the the user inputs.
For example i will write Chrome , explorer , and then the program will close the chosen process.
My only problem is how do i actually close the chosen process aka p.
Code:

```
@echo off
@echo Thank you for using my program.
set /p id=Enter Process Name With .exe in the end:
taskkill p /im explorer.exe
timeout 5
%0
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have come up with so far?  Edit your question to add it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may like to use this line:

```
taskkill /p /im %id%
```

or this one which forces the process closed, but it may corrupt data depending on which program is being forced closed.

```
taskkill /p /f /im %id%
```